# How do I set up Ubuntu 16.04 on my HP Mini so that it automatically connects to my WiFi?

Tags: networking, 16.04, hp

I upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04 on my HP Mini and it went fine, except that the computer would not connect to my WiFi router. I executed the following commands, which re-enabled the WiFi connection:

sudo rmmod -f hp-wmi

sudo rfkill unblock all

rfkill list all

However, when the computer is restarted, it goes back to the same non-WiFi connecting state. What do I need to do to enable WiFi upon startup?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you blacklist the module. From the terminal:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist hp-wmi"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Reboot and let us hear your result.

Comment: Is the line

**echo "blacklist hp-wmi"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf**

two separate commands? If so, I get "Permission denied" when I type **/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf**

(I also tried typing that line as one line verbatim.)

The netbook didn't connect to the router upon restart.

On top of that, the commands I used to make the wifi work in the first place don't work anymore. Entering **sudo rmmod -f hp-wmi** gives the error message: **../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:793 kmod_module_remove_module() could not remove 'hp_wmi': No such file or directory**.

Comment: It is one long command. Do you suspect that the blacklist file is now corrupt? Check: `cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` The last line should read: `blacklist hp-wmi` If not, we'll edit the file by hand.

Comment: The last line does, in fact, read **blacklist hp-wmi**.